# How to call .get() method on this JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

First, look at this screenshot:

[image: Console]

I would like to call `.get("p" + number)` on this, but however I try to do this I get `undefined` or this:

```
Global.refPatients["_object"].get(p151833309)

Uncaught TypeError: Global.refPatients._object.get is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:31
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Comment: `Global.refPatients["_object"].p151833309`? There is no built-in `get` method on objects, and `p151833309` isn’t a variable.

Comment: Nope, `still it is not a function`

Comment: What is not a function? There is no function being called there, so it’s impossible for you to get the same error.

Comment: First, what are you trying to do? What do you think the (non-existent) `get()` method should do? Having asked that, it looks like you're trying to retrieve value held in that object key, so perhaps you want: `Global.refPatients.p151833309`?

Comment: `Global.refPatients["_object"]["p" + number]`?

Comment: Yup, sorry, I've added. get() at the end, your line works, but how do i place a var in place of pp151833309 ? I would like to pass that object to a variable..

Comment: Global.refPatients["_object"]["p" + id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, objects don't have a `get` method. If you want to access the value of a particular property, you can just reference the property with either the bracket or the dot notation (see [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) on MDN):

```
//dot notation:
 Global.refPatients["_object"].p151833309;

//bracket notation - needed if you want to get 15183309 from a variable:
Global.refPatients["_object"]["p"+151833309];
```

Comment: Actually i found out that i can do something like this: `Global.refPatients.get("p151954902")` which i think is less complicated than your solution, anyway, thank you! ;)

Comment: @MichałGątkowski that must be a custom method defined on `refPatients`  or its prototype then, regular Javascript objects don't have a `get` method.